# PHP - Convert characters to a number

Tags: php, string, math, random

**Let's say I have a string like this:**

```
whateverthisis123 #_-
```

I want to convert this string into a number within a number interval forexample within 1-1000.

**The above string could for example be converted into**

```
387
```

**This comes with a few rules:**

- The string could contain every character.
- The number should feel random but cannot be. The same string should always return the same number.
- Longer string should not make the number higher. Should feel random.
- aaa should not give a number like 222. Should feel random.
- It should accept the interval for example 1 up to 1000.
- "thisstring" and "thisstring1" are alike. The numbers should still not be alike.

Is there a built in function for this in PHP? If not, any clever idea how to create something like this?

Maybe it's easier if first converting in to MD5? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: You can convert it to md5, take out the first 3 digit, and comvert them back to decimal*1000/4095 and you will get the number range max possible at 1000

Comment: Thanks for vote me as the correct answer!! I got +25 reps , thanks haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended from my comment, here is a full code example (more fun way than just hash..)

```
 <?php
  function numberout(string $input)
      {
         $hash=md5($input);
         $calculate=hexdec(substr($hash,0,3)); //take out 3 digits
         $maxhex=4095; //3 digit hex ,65535 for 4 digit hex and so on...
         $out = ($calculate*1000)/$maxhex;
         return round($out);
      }
 ?>
```

Sorry if this is programmartically wrong, I was used to c# and I haven't test this yet. So if there is any error I hope someone to edit it

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially describing a hash function. MD5 looks like the way to go. If you need to convert it to a number you could `intval()` it. To keep it between 1-1000, use `$number % 1000`.

Note: If this has to do with security/passwords, it's a bad idea.

Comment: @OP If you're using this as a method of security in any aspect, please consider using [bcrpyt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) as opposed to MD5. MD5's lack of uniqueness makes it vulnerable to multiple attacks.

Comment: No, I'm not going to use it for security. I might have a URL to a quote and on that URL I want a "random" avatar image. This function will create a link to for example 387.jpg for that URL.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case then. Just wanted to make sure!

Comment: I tested it and almost always I get 0 in result. It seems like the intval returns 0 in many cases.